# Display Large Image in c#

Tags: c#, printing, resize

I want to display a large image into a small rectangle using C#.
The problem is that when I do not adjust the rectangle size and image, only half portion of image is displayed every time. Is there any way to print the image completely in the bounds defined? I mean that can the image re-size itself to the rectangle size?

Following is my code:

```
int imagePrintHeight = this.PaperSize.Width - this.PrintMargins.Top - this.PrintMargins.Bottom;
 int imagePrintWidth = this.PaperSize.Height - this.PrintMargins.Left - this.PrintMargins.Right;

Size DatestoPrintSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(DatestoPrint, new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 10));

                            y = y + descriptionSize.Height + DatestoPrintSize.Height;
                            imagePrintHeight = imagePrintHeight - descriptionSize.Height - DatestoPrintSize.Height;

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(objCurrentPrintJob.sDescription, new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x + (imagePrintWidth - descriptionSize.Width) / 2, this.PrintMargins.Top);
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(DatestoPrint, new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), x + (imagePrintWidth - DatestoPrintSize.Width) / 2, this.PrintMargins.Top + descriptionSize.Height);
                        }

                        decimal ratio = Math.Round(decimal.Divide(imagetoPrint.Width, imagetoPrint.Height), 4);
                        int tempimagePrintWidth = (int)(Math.Round(imagePrintHeight * ratio, 4));
                        x += (int)((imagePrintWidth - tempimagePrintWidth) / 2);
```

To print i use following

```
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagetoPrint, new Rectangle(x,y ,tempimagePrintWidth,imagePrintHeight));
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful? Please accept it in that case, or provide more info if you're still having problems.

Comment: @ekholm the provided answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood the question then, or there is something else that is wrong. If you still need help, please clarify what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems you are trying to fit the image to the available page size. Looks like you mix up width and height when assigning imagePrintHeight and imagePrintWidth. I would do the scaling something like this, it will also allow for different relations between the image and page aspect ratios:

```
int imagePrintHeight = this.PaperSize.Height- this.PrintMargins.Top - this.PrintMargins.Bottom;
int imagePrintWidth = this.PaperSize.Width- this.PrintMargins.Left - this.PrintMargins.Right;

// Draw description string here...

double ratio = Math.Min((double)imagePrintWidth / (double)imagetoPrint.Width, (double)imagePrintHeight / (double)imagetoPrint.Height);
int scaledImageWidth = (int)(ratio * imageWidth);
int scaledImageHeight = (int)(ratio * imageHeight);

x = (int)((imagePrintWidth - scaledImageWidth ) / 2);
```